# Can I enter the Schengen area a few days before my student visa expires?

Tags: visas, schengen, portugal

Please take time to read my post and I would appreciate any help. I am currently in Portugal with a type D Visa (Residence) because I am a student in Portugal.

My visa ends on January 10 and I have been able to get an appointment for my residence permit only in April due to the huge amount of people applying.

The Portuguese authorities (sef) told me that I can stay in Portugal even after my visa expires because I already have an appointment for my residence permit in April. But this doesn't allow me to travel after January 10 because it will make it impossible for me to return back due to the expiry of the visa.

I am planning to visit my family abroad (outside the Schengen area) in December until January. So if my visa ends on January 10, is it possible to come back to Portugal on January 6? Or will I face problems at the airport?

Comment: Did you ask SEF about this?

Comment: Yes but they have not answered!!

Answer (score 1):

As long as the visa is valid, you can enter, seeing as your legal status will continue after its expiry due to your pending application for a residence permit.

So you'll be fine, but if you're worried about check-in staff at the non-Schengen airport denying you boarding (which they shouldn't), ask the Portuguese authorities for a written confirmation in English that your legal status continues after the expiry of the visa.